# Pass parameter to OnClick event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx page with a table. Each row in the table represents a row of data base table (which represents a place).

I need a way to pass to OnClick event (or another event) a parameter.
I can't use the CommandArgument becouse then I will need to know the idPlace string and I just don't know it.
I buld the table with FOR loop.

I need something like:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"
                     runat="server" 
                     ImageUrl="Maps.ico"
                     **CommandArgument = '<%=placesDataTable[0]%>'**         
                     />
```

The main idea that for each place (row) in the table there would be a link to map- a different page which would get the placeId and get the coordinates of the googleMap from another table in data base.

I'm working on it a couple of hours and it's frustrating.

Thanks,
Hila

Here is some parts from the code:

```
<body dir="rtl">

    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="background-color:Fuchsia">

        <!-- Here I will display all the results:-->

        <p style="font-style:italic">Here are the results:</p>

        <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <%
        System.Data.DataTable placesDataTable = (System.Data.DataTable)Session["PlacesDataTable"]; // The table of all the places from the dataBase.
        System.Data.DataRow rowOfPlace;
        for (int i = 0; i < placesDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {             
         <tr>
         <%
             for (int j = 1; j < placesDataTable.Columns.Count; j++)
             {%>
                 <td>
                 <% Response.Write(rowOfPlace[j].ToString()); %>
                 </td>
             <%
             } // end FOR LOOP over the columns 
            // insert MAP column content:
            %>
                 <td>
                     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"
                     runat="server" 
                     ImageUrl="Maps.ico"
                     CommandArgument = '<%placesDataTable[i]%>'         
                     />   
                 </td>
         </tr>
         <%
        }
         %>
    </table>

    </form>
</body>
```

What I want is that when user clicks spesific row (place) I will go to OnClick event IN C# code with the SPECIFIC placeId- and there I'll connect to the data-base, get the coordinates of the place, and Respondr.Rediret to another aspx page- which displays the place on the map. I just need the placeId...

Comment: can you shown some more code and which object you actually want in onclick or any other event?

Comment: I added it on the original message (that was a lot of text for a comment).

Comment: why don't you use repeater to create table? in your case ImageButton is not uniquely identified when clicked and commandARguments are used with databound controls like grid,datalist etc.

Comment: Well... I don't really know what repeater means.
Do you have an example of using this and also of how to use the CommandArguments with it?
And by the way- I'm OK with using some other control than ImageButton.
It just the problem with the identification...

Answer (score 1):

you cam use Repeater itemcommand event to get the commandargument.

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"
                     runat="server" 
                     ImageUrl="Maps.ico"
                     CommandName="MapIt"
                     CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("ID")%>'         
                     />   



protected void rptComments_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {
    if(e.CommandName.ToLower().Equals("mapit")) {
        var id  = int.Parse(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).CommandArgument);

    }
}
```

for more detail have a look at

http://dotnetrush.blogspot.com/2006/12/using-repeater-itemcommand.html

Comment: check this for repeater usage. http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/

Comment: The problem is that I don't need the asp control ID. I need the ID of the place (PlacesTable in sataBase has a primary key which called placeId). How can I pass this parameter?

Comment: Isn't there just a simple way to pass a parameter (placeId) to an event?!

Comment: I would have to change all my project for this repeater...
Thanks.

Comment: ID in commandArgument is not the control ID it is the id column of datatable you bound to repeater, if there exist a column with name ID in datatable.